# Create dynamic list/array of string - int pairs based on XML input

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file that has following structure:

```xml
<root>
  <system name="SYS-NAME">
    <file name="NAME.EXTENTION" md5="HASH" path="PATH;PATH1;PATH2"/>
  </system>
  <system name="SYS-NAME1">
    <file name="NAME.EXTENTION1" md5="HASH1" path="PATH1"/>
    <file name="NAME.EXTENTION1-1" md5="HASH1-2" path="PATH1-2;PATH2-2"/>
  </system>
  <system name="SYS-NAME2">
    <file name="NAME.EXTENTION2" md5="HASH2" path="PATH2;PATH3;PATH4;PATH5"/>
  </system>
</root>
```

I iterate though it and search for specific patterns in path like specific name of date pattern like `2019.08` with following code where I split path and take a look at first element in it:

```cs
foreach ($entry in $osFiles) {
    $entry.path.Split(";") | % {
        $numbTotal++
        $root = $_.Split("\")

        if ($root[0] -match "(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])") {
            $numbPatches++
            ##Need Help Here
        } elseif ($root[0] -eq "NAMED") {
            $numbNAMED++
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is creating a list that will hold dates with their counter assigned. So in example I have paths:

```
2019.08/aaaa
2019.09/bbbb
2019.08/cccc
2019.08/adad
2019.09/aaaa
2019.10/bbbf
```

and as a result list/array should contain info that `2019.08` has `3` files; `2019.09` - `2`;`2019.10` - `1`. I'm completely clueless how to do that. I think I have a brainfart

Comment: Do you want to count/Group-Object these yyyy.mm pathes per system or overall?

Comment: Please update your XML data with representative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder structure:

```
> gci


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
...
d-----        11/08/2019    19:47                2019.08
d-----        11/08/2019    19:47                2019.09
d-----        11/08/2019    19:47                2019.10
...
```

Try to use a [hashtable/dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) and combination with `Get-ChildItems` `-File` parameter:

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem
$actLocation = Get-Location
$dictionary = @{}
$directories | ForEach-Object {

    try{
        if($_.Name -match "(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])"){
            Set-Location $_
            $dictionary[$_.Name] += @(Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -File).Count
        } 
    }
    finally{
        Set-Location $actLocation
    }
}
```

`$dictionary`'s content:

```
> $dictionary

Name                           Value
----                           -----
2019.09                        2
2019.08                        3
2019.10                        1
```

Hope that helps.